# Sorting Dictionary Items Using Python

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a problem;

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
result = requests.get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2020-12-1&end_at=2020-12-13&symbols=USD,TRY&base=USD")
result = json.loads(result.text)
print(result["rates"])
print(sorted(i, key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

And i added the error in the below. I want to sort the dates.

[image: ValueError]

Comment: The variable `i` is missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. Please provide a [mre] as text, not pictures. As part of that, please provide the JSON itself, instead of the `requests.get()` call. You can [edit] the question. Please also use a more descriptive title while you're there.

Comment: Yes @DaniMesejo ,  i = dict((x, y) for x, y in result.items()) i didn't add it to my code editor. Thanks wjandrea , i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `i` has no meaning here, you can do

```py
ra = result["rates"]
ra = sorted(ra, key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
print(ra)
```

This will return a list because dict has no order in Python(always!), you can not put any order on dict elements.

To use a ordered dict, you can try `OrderedDict` in Python, see

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Thank you for your interest!

Comment: In CPython 3.6 and Python 3.7 onwards, dictionaries [started to preserve order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/5704664).

Comment: Thank you @dmitryguzeev this is the first time I know such thing

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing variable `i` is `result`? If that's the case, you can do something like this:

```py
sorted_rates = dict(sorted(
  result["rates"].items(),
  key=lambda item: datetime.strptime(item[0], "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

Here, we first convert the dictionary `result["rates"]` into an array of tuples of the form `(key, value)`. Then we sort that using a comparator function that gets the string date from the tuple by accessing the first element (`item[0]`).

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks :)